# dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct name’

Tags: c

I am trying to write a doubly linked linear list.   I want to display the size of the list, but it displays an error: `dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct List’`.

**main.c**:

```
#include "dlist.h"
#include <stdio.h>
    int main(){
        struct List* l;
        Create(l);
        printf("%d", *(l->size));
        return 0;
}
```

**dlist.c**:

```
typedef int T;
struct Node{
        struct Node* prev;
        struct Node* next;
        T data;
};
struct List {
        struct Node* head;
        int size;
};
void Create(struct List* l){
        l->head = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        l->head->next = NULL;
        l->head->prev = NULL;
        l->size = 0;
}
```

**dlist.h:**

```
typedef int T;
struct Node;
struct List;
void Create(struct List* Item);
```

Comment: post the stacktrace

Comment: @Raju: how do you get a stack trace from code that doesn't even compile?

Comment: `l->size` by itself should work.

Comment: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct List’
  printf("%d", l->size);

Comment: problem in your code is you are not intialized the `struct List l`

Comment: You need `#include <stdlib.h>` and then what @FiddlingBits mentioned.

Comment: The declaration of `struct List` needs to be in scope for the function `main`.  Probably you should put it in `dlist.h`.  What are the contents of that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By declaring the structure type in your header but not including its definition there (that is, its member list), you have created an *opaque type*.  Because code outside of **dist.c** does not have the definition, it cannot declare objects of that type or access their members.  The type is opaque to such code.

But it can create and deal in *pointers to* objects of that type, which does not require information about the size or members of that type.  This is why the compiler does not object until it reaches the `printf` call, whose second argument is an expression that attempts to access a member of a `struct List`, whose definition is not visible in that scope.

There are two possible directions to go from here.  One would be to move the definition of `struct List` into **dist.h**, and probably also that of `struct Node`.  **dist.c** would then `#include` that header to get those, just like everyone else, and in `main()` you would be able to access the structure members directly, as you are trying to do.

The other way, used when a type is intentionally made opaque, is to provide  appropriate functions for operating on objects of your type, for example:

```
int get_size(struct List *list) {
    return list->size;
}
```

That would go in **dist.c** alongside your `Create()` function, with a declaration in **dist.h**, and your `main()` would call it to get the list size.

And speaking of your `Create()` function, it is <s>broken</s> misleadingly named, and your usage of it is incorrect (which, combined, led me initially to call it broken).  You are presently passing an uninitialized pointer to it, which is useless, and which is a key contributor to the undefined behavior that arises when `Create()` then attempts to access an object through that pointer.

An initialization function such as your `Create()` is ok, and can work with either approach, but for the opaque type approach you do need a *bona fide* instance creation function, since you cannot declare objects of an opaque type.  Such a function would typically return a pointer to the created object.  It would be natural for such a function also to perform initialization, and in many cases that would moot a separate initialization-only function.

Comment: I don't think the `Create()` function is necessary broken. In fact it doesn't try to change  `l`, but it just changes its data. It behaves as a C++ constructor. What is broken is its use in `main()`. To make it work, `l` should be a `struct List` and it should be passed as `Create(&l);`. The later direct access to the `size` member should then be done with `l.size`.

Comment: I have substantially revised my comments about your `Create()` function, @CostantinoGrana.  Although I agree that it is not broken *per se*, your program's *usage* of it is definitely broken, and there are tie-ins to the matters discussed in the preceding parts of the answer.

Comment: Your comments on the usage were totally right and also your answer. I was just noting that the idea of requiring an already allocated list object could have worked. There's also the not so smart idea of allocating the head node even when the size is set to zero.

Comment: Moreover your answer is very nice, since I'd have advocated for putting the struct in the .h as a requirement. I totally missed to notice that you could work with objects of which you don't know the inner workings.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be importing "dlist.h" while all the declarations appear in the implementation file AKA "dlist.c".

You should place your visible declarations to the ".h" file.
And not only types - function declaration too.

Comment: Why are you struct List everywhere instead of just using a typedef?

Comment: Functions and structures were declared in the header file.

Comment: I thought the problem was this and did not use typedef

Comment: Why should they use a `typedef`, @MoisésFerreira?  That's entirely a style consideration.  Personally, I think `typedef`s are greatly overused, and I prefer to see and use the `struct <tag>`  form of type designator for structure types.

Comment: @JohnBollinger ty!